# Using Selenium to extract a link from text

Tags: python

Using Selenium, I'm trying to return the link path from an element. A page has a text link 'Information for customers who are off-grid or in an embedded network'. I have used the following methods:

```
link_href = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-search-form"]/div/section/div[2]/div/div[1]').get_attribute("href")
link_href2 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#react-search-form > div > section > div.v2-form-item > div > div.v2-link').get_attribute("href")
link_text = browser.find_element_by_class_name('v2-link').text

print(f"""
Link href: {link_href}
Link href2: {link_href2}
Link text: {link_text}
""")
```

This returns the following:

```
Link href: None
Link href2: None
Link text: Information for customers who are off-grid or in an embedded network
```

How do I get the link path returned for link_href and link_href2?

Comment: Have you tried `find_element_by_link_text`?